# Web Api IIS Angular: Api отправляет 401, а Angular принимает 500

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

Имею фронт на Angular, бек Web Api.
Есть метод, который отправляет некоторую инфу только авторизованным пользователям. Иначе `return Unauthorized();` Локально все работает, после публикации фронт стабильно получает 500. Выкинул из метода все, оставил только ответ, результат не поменялся

```
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAuthorized()
        {
            try
            {                             
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Ok(ex.StackTrace);
            }    
        }
```

Код фронта

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUserClaims().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.userClaims = data;
    },
    err => console.log(err));
  }
```

В итоге следующее.

- localhost. Win 10, .net 4.7.1
- server: Win Server 2008 R2, .net 4.7.1

на локале: swagger получает 401, фронт тоже получает 401;
на сервере: swagger получает 500, фронт 500.

Web.config одинаковый. Куда копать уже не понимаю.

***Edited***
В целом мне помогла статья https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205599/asp-net-web-api-correct-way-to-return-a-401-unauthorised-response
Но на вопрос "почему так?" она не отвечает

Comment: а какая ошибка 500, что там написано?

Comment: {headers: t, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", message: "Http failure response for : 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: А в iis на серваке есть нужный вам вид авторизации? (по умолчанию там его нету) Возможно в виндовом features нужно галок доставить.

Comment: Не знаю, надо смотреть. В любом случае, авторизация проходит. Т.е. токен получается и успешно валидируется. К защищенным `api` доступ дается. Такое чувство, что суть именно в `Unauthorized();`. Для себя я решение нашел, но интересно в чем же здесь суть.